# Python regex to match 'category/' or 'categories/'?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using `^category/|categories/$`.

Why does `^categor[y|ies]/$` not work?

Comment: Square brackets create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches a single character in the list.

Comment: It doesn't work because `[y|ies]` means "y, or i or e or s", not what you want which is `y` or `ies`.  If this is for django urls, you can map both urls to the same view, to get your desired effect.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I figured I would want to have the same `urlpattern` handle both `category` as well as `categories`, DRY and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex should be,

```
^categor(?:y|ies)/$
```

Use a non-capturing group instead of character class.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fL6sV3/3)

Any special character inside character class are treated a literals except few. `[y|ies]` Matches a single character whether it may be `y` or `|` or `i` or `e` or `s`

```
>>> import re
>>> str = """
... category/
... categories/
... categories
... category"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^categor(?:y|ies)/$', str, re.MULTILINE)
>>> m
['category/', 'categories/']
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the beginning of the line.
- `categor` Matches the string `categor`.
- `(?:y|ies)` The above string `categor` must be followed be `y` or `ies`. In regex `(?:)` called non-capturing groups. It only do a matching operation not capturing.
- `/` Matches a  literal forward slash `/`.
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: Just wondering, Why non-capturing? Normal grouping also works.

Comment: @mhawke you mean this `^categor(y|ies)/$`? If i use this regex , i would get the findall function output as `['y', 'ies']`. findall gives first prefence to the groups if no groups are found then only it prints the matched characters. Clear noe?

Comment: so it does - thanks for the explanation. I was only considering `re.match()`.